# How would I join two tables, A and B, on A.slug and B.path in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have an `articles` table that has a column called `slugs`, storing the slugs of the article - for example `example-article-2016`.

I also have a `log` table that logs each visit to each article, and has a column called `paths` that stores the same data in a different format: `/articles/example-article-2016`.

I have thought about just processing the `path` column in a way that would remove the `/articles/` part, and then joining, but I am curious if there is a way to join on these columns without actually modifying the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to actually modify the data permanently, but you do have to adjust it for the join.  One way would be to replace `/articles/` with `''` for example:

```
SELECT ...
FROM articles a
JOIN log l ON REPLACE(l.paths, '/articles/', '') = a.slugs
```

This won't use indexes and is not ideal, but works perfectly fine in ad-hoc scenarios.  If you need to do this join a lot, you should consider a schema change.

Comment: This is simple and works great. Thanks for the quick response, @Aaron!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
SELECT
    a.slugs /*, l.visited_at */
FROM
    articles a
    JOIN logs l ON substr(l.path, length('/articles/')+1) = a.slugs ;
```

The `substr` function should be quite fast to execute. You can obviously change `length('/articles/')+1` by the constant `11`; but I think that leaving it there is much more informative of what you're actually doing... If the last bit of performance is needed, put the `11`.

You will probably take benefit of having the following computed index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_logs_slug_from_path 
    ON logs ((substr(path, length('/articles/')+1))) ;
```

Check the whole setup at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a507e3bd900a63891f3a9fcade81887e)*